# How do I be less on fire?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

On a few occasions now, I've encountered enemies wielding a gun that shoots *fire*. Symptoms of being on fire include barbecuing to death. The speed of said barbecuing varies on whether or not you continue to be beset by the wielder of the mysterious flame-gouting weapon. When I have managed to escape, I remain aflame, and still die.

How do I put myself out? *How do I be less on fire?*

Comment: I'd probably prefer "How do I not DIAF (die in a fire)?"

Comment: @NickT i would agree but thats not exactly what he is asking, im trying to think of a better way to word his question without changing it completely.

Comment: I do believe I am on fire.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that the game doesn't have a Stop, Drop, and Roll option?

Comment: Why did you revert Paralytic's edit? "How do i be less on fire" is horrible English.

Comment: @kotekzot It's for humor purposes. IF it is *really* determined that the meaning of this question cannot be determined with the current title, "How do I put myself out?" would be the obvious phrasing. Secondarily, he changed the third to last sentence to present tense instead of past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't put it out. The only thing you can do is run to a supplystation and hope it heals you fast enough until the fire stops after some time automatically.

A medpack from a medic can also heal you enough to survive the fire.

If the enemy is using the BBQ Kit, you want to avoid small rooms, since they are really very strong in those. Out in the open, they are cannon fodder since the Support class wielding the BBQ Kit can't take a lot of Damage.

http://forums.interwavestudios.com/wiki/index.php/Support#BBQ_Kit

Comment: Supply stations and medikits remove the fire effect instantly, so the best option is to run to either and hope to survive long enough to get there.